# Rails 2.3.14: How to serialise an ActionController::Request object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, marshalling

I need to write some methods that Do Things based on the kind of request object received by a Rails 2.3.14 controller.  However, I don't want to fire up the entire application, nor even a controller; I'd like to have just a marshalled copy of such an object that I can work with outside of the Rails environment.

Unfortunately, the `ActionController::Request` objects passed to controllers include, deep in their bowels, `Proc` objects which are inherently unserialisable.

Does anyone know of a way to serialise one of these objects such that I can store it away in a data file and re-create it in another script?  I would prefer not to monkey-patch the `Proc` class to provide a `#marshal_dump` method..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to replace/delete not serializable objects (especially in the env-hash). I implemented parts of it in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790124/yaml-typeerror-cant-dump-anonymous-module/16025579#answer-16025579). I slightly updated my approach using a rails 3.2.13 `request` object.

```
##
# build a serializable hash out of the given request object
def make_request_serializable(request)
  request_hash = {
    :env => request.env.clone,
    :filtered_parameters => request.filtered_parameters.clone,
    :fullpath => request.fullpath,
    :method => request.method,
    :request_method => request.request_method
  }
  #clean up the env-hash, as it contains not serializable objects
  request_hash[:env].tap do |env|
    env.delete "action_dispatch.routes"
    env.delete "action_dispatch.logger"
    env.delete "action_controller.instance"
    env.delete "rack.errors"
    env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"] = env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"].to_s 
  end
  request_hash
end

# later in the controller
puts make_request_serializable(request).to_json
#=> {"env":{"SERVER_SOFTWARE":"thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor","SERVER_NAME":"localhost","rack.input":[],"rack.version":[1,0], ... (shortened, as it's a lot of output)
```

---

**Update**: owww, I've just seen that you are asking vor Rails `2.3.14`. My visual filter let me see `3.2.14` instead. So this only works for a current rails version, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the start, I've improved this a lot and shared the code on the other question here:   http://stackoverflow.com/a/26080556/25192